# electric potential of electric dipole in 2D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential

I have the homework question as follows.
[image]

What I did was first find that 
$$\phi = \frac{-\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}(\ln(r_+)-\ln(r_-))=\frac{-\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\frac{r_+}{r_-}\right).$$
I then proceeded to find formulas for $r_+$ and $r_-$ (which are the distances a given point is from the positive and negative charge respectively) in terms of $x$ and $y$ for different cases but I found that this yields an answer that is always zero that passes through the midpoint along the line perpendicular to the line joining the charges  (which is clearly incorrect).

I am stuck and don't know what to do.

Comment: Why do you think that the electrostatic potential at a point equidistant between two charges of equal magnitude and opposite sign should be nonzero? Wouldn't you expect them to cancel exactly?

Comment: True. But then won’t the electric field be zero?

Comment: No. Zero potential, at a given point in space, does not mean zero electric field at that point. The field is minus the gradient of the potential. So, at points on that bisecting line, it will be perpendicular to the bisecting line, and parallel to the line joining the two charges.

Comment: The problem is that I have the formula for potential $\phi = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi \epsilon _0} \ln(\sqrt{\frac{x^2 + (y-a)^2}{x^2 + (y+a)^2}})$ for $0\leq y \leq a$ where $y$ is the axis joining the points. When we take the derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $x$ or $y$ and set $y=0$ (the bisecting line) we have $E=0$. have I done somthing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I suspect you have made a slip in doing the differentiation. If the charges are at $x=0$, $y=\pm a$, the derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $y$ should not vanish, for example at $x=y=0$.